# .htaccess to route request to current folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm writing a custom PHP framework for use on my projects and I'm having some issues loading the CSS, JS and image files.

The following code is in my .htaccess file -

```
RewriteEngine On
#rewrite to base folder
RewriteBase /SimplexFramework/

#add trailing slashes
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This basically states that redirect request to index.php if the path doesn't point to a file.

Following is my directory structure. CSS, JS folders are present under `files`.
[image]

My view files are located in `app/view`, I'm loading the CSS and JS files through the path - `files/css/style.css` or `files/js/script.js`

When my URL in the browser is `http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/` things work as expected.

When the URL changes to `http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/Users/login` for example, apache can no longer find the files as expected.

In the browser I see the following request made -

`http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/User/register/files/js/scrits.js`

Can I ask apache to look for files from the folder in which I have .htaccess. Something similar to `RewriteBase` ?

Comment: You need to set the css/js include as an absolute path, not a relative one. You can see this by doing this: `/files/js/script.js`

Comment: @Darren - I tried that, but then the request redirects to -

http://localhost:8081/files/js/script.js

Is the RewriteBase not working?

Comment: What environment variables do you set in your `index.php` file? You could simple set something like this: `DEFINE('ASSET_PATH', '/SimplexFramework/path/to/assets/')` and called it: `<script src="<?php echo ASSET_PATH; ?>js/script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have relative URLs in your content, it's up to the browser to figure out how to load them. This has *nothing* to do with htaccess or rewrite rules.

Say a browser loads this url: `http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/Users/login`

And on that page's content, it see's a link: `<script src="files/js/scripts.js">`

Since the link is relative (doesn't start with a "http" or "/"), the browser now has to guess what the relative URL base is, and the only thing it has to work with is the URL. So the last path in the URL is "login", and it drops that and uses the basename as the URL base, so it gets:

```
http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/Users/files/js/scripts.js
```

This is 100% a relative/absolute URL issue and has nothing to do with your rules and nothing to do with `RewriteBase`. It's because your links are relative and the URL base has changed from `http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/` to `http://localhost:8081/SimplexFramework/some/stuff/that/eventually/gets/rewritten/`.

To fix this, make your URL's absolute: `<script src="/SimplexFramework/files/js/scripts.js">`

or add the correct URL base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/SimplexFramework/" />
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to write a helper in my framework that will load the css and scripts. Otherwise, moving this to prod will be a nightmare.